# Sharing Nested Angular 2/4 Services

Tags: angular

Can services of child modules be shared with parent or sibling modules within Angular?  If so, how?

```
App Module
\ Common Module
  \ Core Module
    \ Authentication Service
    \ Event Handler Service
    \ Logger Service
  \ Data Service
\ Login Module
\ Dashboard Module
```

In the structure above, I want to declare **Authentication, EventHandler, and Logger services** in my **Core** module, etc.

My goal is for my services **in Login and Dashboard** modules to be able to use all of the services I created in Core.  I **do not** want to re-declare all of those services in App, Login, or Dashboard (providers, etc.).

I've just finished watching several courses and they ALL stress registering the services in the **App Module's providers** array.  Even though they created nested modules they NEVER mention the scenario above.

The courses I'm talking about are:

[Angular: Getting Started](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents) by Deborah Kurata
[Angular CLI](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-cli/table-of-contents) by [John Papa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13375/john-papa)
[Angular : First Look](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angular-2-first-look) by [John Papa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13375/john-papa)

Comment: are you using lazy loading for modules or they are all eagerly-loaded
?

Comment: I'd prefer lazy loading them, but my brain is so fried that I don't really care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you gotten to the module in my course on "Angular Modules"? I cover this here:

> Any service provider added to the providers array is registered at the
>   root of the application.  So the service is available to be injected
>   into *any* class in the application.

And this example:

> Say for example we have a feature module called ProductModule. We add
>   the ProductService to the providers array of this module. At first
>   glance, we may think that we have encapsulated the ProductService into
>   the ProductModule. But that is not the case. Any service provider
>   added to the providers array is registered at the root of the
>   application and is available to *any* class, even classes in other
>   feature modules.

Does the above cover your scenario as well?

And then this:

> As discussed in the "Services and Dependency Injection" course module,
>   there should only be one instance of a service that is an
>   application-wide singleton. So a service should not be included in the
>   providers array for any module that is meant to be shared. 
>   Instead, consider building a Core module for services and importing it
>   once in the AppModule. This will help ensure that the services are
>   only registered one time.

Let me know if this does not help and I'll look to clarify this further in the next update of my course.

Here is an example core module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    DataService,
    MessageService
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

I'm registering my `DataService` and `MessageService` here.

Then pull in the Core module like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './home/page-not-found.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

/* Feature Modules */
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { MessageModule } from './messages/message.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    UserModule,
    MessageModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now the services registered in the CoreModule are available to *every* component, service, or other class in the entire application.

You use the service like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MessageService } from '../core/message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  get displayMessages(): boolean {
    return this.messageService.displayMessages;
  }

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }
 // ...

}
```

To use **anything** in a code file you need to add an import statement for that thing. So you'll still need to add an import statement your services before you can use them in any component/class/pipe/service/etc that needs them.

Comment: I have.  Yaaaay!  (love that)  This is the problem.  I don't want to register the services in the root app.  It feels wrong.  If I have a "shared" or "common" module, with 15-20 common services, then there should be a way of saying "make all of those services available everywhere"... without having to go back into App module.  This is the way AngularJS works.  I'm having a hard time accepting that an IMPROVED version would make it more difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it is more difficult? Register the services in the Core module. Then include the App module bring in the Core module. (Everything for an Angular app has to be tied in some way to the App module). I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: This might just be the missing link [for me].  By adding `CoreModule` to the App Module's `imports` array, the individual services, contained within Core (ie LoggerService, AuthService, etc.) are automatically available to the other modules and services (ie WelcomeComponent, AppRoutingModule, MessageModule, etc.).  Is this correct?  The 15-20 services WITHIN CoreModule do not have to be imported anywhere else or added to another module's `providers` array?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes that they do not need to be added to any other module's providers array. However, every time you use **anything** in a code file you have to add an import statement for that thing. I'll update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I think you just hit the nail on the head... the reason for my confusion... using both the "import" statement AND declaring it in the App.  This seems so illogical!  Having come from C#/VB.NET, I understand adding a `using` or `import` statement to register a type within my class file.  However, to then declare it in a SECOND location (the App module) just seems wrong.  What does that second step provide?  The only answer I can come up with is registering it in the app allows the service to become a singleton somehow.  No?

Comment: Coming from .NET this should make perfect sense. You can't use any System.XXX or other library unless you first add a reference to it in your project. (Right click | Add Reference). Then you ALSO use an import or using statement before you can use it in any code file. So this is the same, except instead of "Add Reference" you add it to a module. Does that help?

Comment: In general ... you can even think of an Angular module as somewhat similar to a .NET project. It is where you define the list of files in the project along with the set of "references" defining all of the external libraries that the project uses.

Comment: Greeeeat analogy!  (Or, at least it's a great excuse to force my brain to accept it).  I think I'm getting it.  Yaaaaay!  :)

Comment: Great! It is amazing how close Angular is now to something like C# ... especially when using TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand that if you don't use lazy-loaded modules there's no hierarchy between modules. All modules and respective services are merged into single module factory which is then used to create a global injector.

With lazy-loaded modules you do get hierarchy but services from child modules can access services from the parent modules.

> My goal is for my services in Login and Dashboard modules to be able
>   to use all of the services I created in Core

So if your Core module is eagerly loaded, every service declared in the modules will be available throughout application.

The article [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f) explains this topic in depth.